# how to trigger the scheduled job which has parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

How to schedule the parameterized jenkins job?

I have a parameterized parent job which has 6 child jobs. when the parent job is triggered it should start the child jobs one after another.I should run the parent job for every 7 hours on weekend which I have given as `H */7 * * 6-7`.

My questions are:

1. How does the parent job takes the parameters when it is triggered?
2. Does it take the default choice or do i need a script to give the parameters?
3. How to configure if i want to skip any one of the child job?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Parameterized Scheduler Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Scheduler+Plugin)

1) Here's an example of passing parameters via the scheduler. If your job is parameterized, the plugin will add an option "*Build periodically with parameters*".

```
H */7 * * 6-7 % Environment=development; Version=2,4,3
```

2) I don't think it honors a default, I have not seen that in the docs. Let us know if you find something.

3) Via the parameters?

Comment: parameterized scheduler plugin is installed 
1) but when i give it is showing Invalid input: "H */7 * * 6-7 % TEST_ENV_BRANCH=origin/master;": line 1:14: expecting EOF, found ' '

2) i was able to trigger my jobs by setting the required parameters as default.

3) I found the answer. I unchecked the child job in the configurations

Comment: H */7 * * 6-7 % TEST_ENV_BRANCH=origin/master line 1:14: expecting EOF, found
when i give this is giving me an error on jenkins

Comment: I wonder if it's not liking the slash "/" that you have in your parameter between origin and master? Just a guess. You might try the parameter without the slash just to see if the error goes away.

Comment: I tried with H */7 * * 6-7 % LINUX=ubuntu but i see the same error expecting EOF

Comment: I think the problem is that you're choosing "Build periodically" instead of "Build periodically with parameters".

Comment: Do you have parameters defined on your job? The option won't show up unless you do. You should have a parameter defined on your job for each parameter you want to pass.

Comment: yes the parameters are defined in my job and the option this build is parameterized is checked

Comment: Hmm OK good. And you've double checked that you have the "Parameterized Scheduler Plugin" installed, right?

Comment: I'm not sure why the "Build periodically with parameters" option is not showing up for you, sorry. You might want to try one of the IRC channels - https://jenkins.io/chat/