# In Jenkins, is there a timeout for Build with Parameters?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins, I know that `input` can be combined with `timeout` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234204/timeout-on-a-build-step-of-jenkins)), but what about `Build with Parameters`?

My (maybe incorrect) thought is to have "default" parameters set on a declarative pipeline Jenkinsfile, so that if a human runs it, he can enter the parameters, but when it runs periodically (e.g., daily at 12pm), the prompt is not required and the "default" parameters are used.

Comment: If you wan't the automatic builds to use the default parameters, then you should be able to use a regular periodic scheduled trigger, and the users will be able to build using build with parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct with regard to setting default values and can do this:

```
options {
    timeout(time: params.timeoutTime, unit: params.timeoutUnit)
}
parameters {
    string(name: 'timeoutTime', defaultValue: '30', description: '')
    string(name: 'timeoutUnit', defaultValue: 'MINUTES', description: '')
}
```

When you trigger the build manually, it will use the parameters that you provide. For timer triggered builds, it will use the default values.

Comment: Thank you! Before you posted this, I had solved my own question with the Extended Choice Parameter plugin (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) which allows default values in the Jenkinsfile (https://github.com/jenkinsci/extended-choice-parameter-plugin/pull/25).

Comment: This seems to sometimes result in a timeout of 0 for me, not sure why it's inconsistent

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're looking for is the parameterized scheduler plugin perhaps? See my answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56296420/how-to-trigger-the-scheduled-job-which-has-parameters/56298678#56298678)